# When do the toad houses restock their inventory?

Tags: new-super-mario-bros-2

I need some of the goodies from the toad houses to investigate some secrets.  But I just used up the Star (yellow) toad house.  When will toad houses restock their goodies (for each of red, yellow and green)?

Answer (score 1):

The times are different for each.
Red: 5-9 minutes
Yellow: 20-25 minutes
Green: 10-19 minutes

Comment: Minutes in real-time, or play-time?

Comment: Its based on real time.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be real time. I grabbed a Gold flower from a Star house, closed the 3DS and did other stuff for an hour or so - the Star house was still closed. Then I played for over an hour, and the star house still hadn't re-opened.

Comment: Gold flower as the item takes 4 playing days (approx 3 hours 15 minutes 29 seconds) to restock the flower.